# Backbone, Ember or Knockout scaffolder for webapi and ASPNET MVC 4 with jquery grids

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Is there a scaffolder that works with Backbone, Ember or Knockout or any other framework to scaffold webapi/aspnet mvc 4 project that uses Entity Framework 5 and is able to scaffold the view with jquery grids?

Better, would be a not SPA scaffolder, I mean, a scaffolder that work with ASPNET MVC 4 and WebApi using jquery to call WebApi controller's REST methods.

I couldn't find anyone out there, only ControllerWithAjaxGrid but it retrieves Views as result and I want to make REST operations from the View to the WebApi controllers.

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: Have a look at this http://nuget.org/packages/SinglePageApplication

Comment: I think that one was turned down/delayed because it was not complete.